# Android setting alarm to a past date

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, alarm

What happens should I add an alarm but set the starting date to a past date?

Does is get executed immediately or is it put in the queue and never executed?

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startDate, repeatingValue, alarmIntent);
```

Comment: try your self and test it very simple :)

Comment: use Use `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating`..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the date is in past then alarm will trigger immediately. However you may try to use `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating`:

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startDate, setInexactRepeating , alarmIntent);
```

From the [setInexactRepeating() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)):

> Schedule a repeating alarm that has inexact trigger time requirements;
>   for example, an alarm that repeats every hour, but not necessarily at
>   the top of every hour.

Answer (score 8):

From [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)), if the startDate time is in the past, the alarm will be triggered immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Actually AlarmManager works with the current time.
So when you will set past date alarm then AlarmManager will execute

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
}
```

method.

Answer (score 0):

I think the alarm is set only for hours(at least through the Android user interface), not for a particular day, this way it will start on the exact `hour:minute` you set.

Answer (score 0):

As i can conclude from my previous experience with `AlarmManager`. Date that is in the past will trigger alarm immediately.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, *AlarmManager.set* will execute now when the time is set to a past time, the documentation says as much. This sentence is missing for *AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating* , this alarm will not trigger when it's set for a past time, it will trigger at the next interval, starting from the given time.

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager.set and AlarmManager.setInexactRepeating are both calling setImpl, with the triggertime they got passed as parameter (checked in Android 7.1.2 sources).
--> there's no difference in both methods, if the triggertime is in the past.